# Set limit to IP for downloading content/data in static HTML site

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, gallery, cpanel

My website is a photo gallery in static HTML pages. No php, sql or any scripts except Google analytics scripts.

I know that its not possible to fully protect the website content. There is many programs to download images in bulk.

But I want someway to limit a IP for a period of time/day when their/IP downloaded content reaches for example 1GB. (in .htaccess may be?)

I am using Cpanel in VPS and the website content is easily downloadable from image grabbers and there's also no login functions in website. I dont know how to protect the images. So setting a limit to IP possible?

Is Block bad user agents codes like below in htaccess work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet
```

***I did searched before posting this question because same kind of questions have been asked before but they are all related to scripts, php, sql websites but not asked for a static html websites (I think so).

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup that limit with the iptables. Please check it https://serverfault.com/questions/384132/iptables-limit-rate-of-a-specific-incoming-ip and try to setup it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checking that now. I am not expert in this field so kinda confusing there and worried about this line.. "Note that mucking around with this without knowing what is going on may lead to you losing network connectivity to the machine! You have been warned!"  
Hope there's another way but have to learn it if it does the job. :)